# FIX @media Queries / @media code for each individual screen size

Tags: css, media-queries

Website issue to fix:

I’m trying to figure out why some of my @media queries are overlapping. If you look at my code you can see the @media queries are labeled for each device dimension.

```
@media SCREEN SIZE: MASSIVE
@media SCREEN SIZE: LARGE
@media SCREEN SIZE: MEDIUM 
@media SCREEN SIZE: IPAD
@media SCREEN SIZE: SMALL TABLET
```

The goal is to be able to change font sizes and image sizes for each unique @media / SCREEN SIZE.

Problem: For some reason when I make changes to the image sizes or text sizes on “SCREEN SIZE: MEDIUM” it also apply’s the changes to all the other @media larger screen sizes.

However, I am able to individually change the header background “#header {background:url(../img/super” for each individual @media code just fine without it erroneously changing the background on all the @media / SCREEN SIZE’s.

How can I get the css @media codes to be completely unique to it’s own @media / SCREEN SIZE without affecting the other @media / SCREEN SIZE’s?

And how can I add the final @media for the small phone size (Website currently shows all messed up on a small phone size)?

Let me know the answer. Your all the best!

Answer (score 0):

If you need non-overlapping breakpoints you will have to do something like this

```
/*Small*/
@media (max-width: 499px) { ... }
/*Medium*/
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 999px) { ... }
/*Big*/
@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1499px) { ... }
/*Large*/
@media (min-width: 1500px) { ... }
```